# Does Apple still make iMovie HD available to iLife users?

Tags: imovie

When Apple "upgraded" iMovie back in 2008 from its previous version to the completely rewritten program with a star-shaped icon, they [kept the previous version available for download](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2007/08/apple-makes-imovie-hd-6-available-for-download.ars).

Currently, I can't find the older version of iMovie on Apple's site. My question is either a) is there still a legal way to get iMovie HD or b) when did it cease to be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Apple has removed it from the download section of their site as of about January 26, 2009. See: http://www.macrumors.com/2009/01/27/imovie-hd-6-no-longer-available-for-download/

The direct download link in that article now returns a 404 error.